# A first example from Brad Green's book "AngularJS" has a mistake

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems to be so simple but doesn't work:

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function HelloController($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
      <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

have on the screen:

```
{{greeting.text}}, World
```

and in a console:

```
    Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HelloController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/ng/areq?p0=HelloController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:80:12
    at assertArg (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:1610:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:1620:3)
    at http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:8319:9
    at http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:7496:34
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:343:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:7483:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:6991:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:6994:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:6994:13)
```

Cannot see why... except maybe because I use `AngularJS v1.3.0`?

Comment: Not sure about v1.3.0 but [it works with v1.2.1](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/7rakjukj/). [FYI, v1.3.0 is listed as unstable](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=fr#angularjs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is because of 1.3.0. The [change log](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-13) describes the breaking change as:

> $controller will no longer look for controllers on window. The old behavior of looking on window for controllers was originally intended for use in examples, demos, and toy apps. We found that allowing global controller functions encouraged poor practices, so we resolved to disable this behavior by default.

The change log goes on to explain that you can re-enable the "global" function approach with:

> Although it's not recommended, you can re-enable the old behavior like this:

```
angular.module('myModule').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  // this option might be handy for migrating old apps, but please don't use it
  // in new ones!
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an issue with AngularJS 1.3.0. Another way to circumvent it (maybe simpler and safer) is by explicitly including an older version of AngularJS. For example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a better solution if you are to follow the book and progress according to the book

Answer (score 1):

in Angular 1.4 this is working solution:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
      <input ng-model='greeting.text'>
      <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

controllers.js

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('HelloController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
});
```